# flask sqlalchemy working with relationship in database

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi guys am trying to create a database that has 10 tables, each tables consist of users info and so on. I want to be able to know the owner of the data in another database table, using the referral_ID from the UserProfile Table. all i want is to be able to track and know the owner of each data in another database table. well am trying to track a referral system data, which each and every user will only have one account, but not in the case of the blogpost and chatpost. below is my model code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class UserProfile(db.Model):

__tablename__ = "userprofile"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
privilege = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=True, default='user')
sap_sponsor_ID = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
sap_ID = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
firstName = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
lastName = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
gender = db.Column(db.String(6), nullable=False)
date_of_birth = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
marital_status = db.Column(db.String(7), nullable=False)
about = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
mobile_number = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
country = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
state = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
city = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
home_address = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
profile_picture = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.png')
gap_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
joined_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
account_owner = db.relationship('UserWallet', 'UserTeamWallet', 'BlogPost', 'ChatPost', 'PendingTransactions', 'ConfirmedTransactions',  'WithheldTransactions', backref='owner', lazy=True)


def __repr__(self):
    return f"Users('''\
                    '{self.privilege}', '{self.sap_sponsor_ID}', '{self.sap_ID}'\
                    '{self.firstName}', '{self.lastName}', '{self.email}', '{self.gender}'\
                    '{self.date_of_birth}', '{self.marital_status}', '{self.about}'\
                    '{self.mobile_number}', '{self.country}', '{self.state}', '{self.city}'\
                    '{self.home_address}', '{self.profile_picture}', '{self.gap_ID}'\
                    '{self.joined_date}'\
                    ''')"
```

class UserWallet(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "userwallet"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
stage = db.Column(db.String(7), nullable=False)
rank = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False)
referral = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
wallet_balance = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
sap_wallet = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
sap_activator = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
sap_team = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
first = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
second = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
third = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
mem = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
qua = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
dis = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
sen = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
PB = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
PS = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
PG = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
PP = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
PS = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
PR = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
PD = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
BN = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
SN = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
GN = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
PN = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
Sa = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
RN = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
DN = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
wallet_owned_by = db.Column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('userprofile.sap_ID'), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"UserWallet('''\
                        '{self.stage}', '{self.rank}', '{self.referral}', '{self.wallet_balance}'\
                        '{self.sap_wallet}', '{self.sap_activator}', '{self.sap_team}'\
                        '{self.first}', '{self.second}', '{self.third}', '{self.mem}'\
                        '{self.qua}', '{self.dis}', '{self.sen}'\
                        '{self.PB}', '{self.PS}', '{self.PG}', '{self.PP}', '{self.PS}'\
                        '{self.PR}', '{self.PD}', '{self.BN}', '{self.SN}', '{self.GN}'\
                        '{self.PN}', '{self.Sa}', '{self.RN}', '{self.DN}'\
                        ''')"
```

class UserTeamWallet(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "userteamwallet"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
my_team = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
team_mem = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
team_qua = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
team_dis = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
team_sen = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
TB = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
TS = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
TG = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
TP = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
TS = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
TR = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
TD = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
team_wallet_owned_by = db.Column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('userprofile.sap_ID'), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"UserTeamWallet('''\
                        '{self.my_team}', '{self.team_mem}', '{self.team_qua}'\
                        '{self.team_dis}', '{self.team_sen}', '{self.TB}'\
                        '{self.TS}', '{self.TG}', '{self.TP}', '{self.TS}'\
                        '{self.TR}', '{self.TD}'\
                        ''')"
```

class BlogPost(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "blogpost"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
post_picture = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default_post.png')
date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
blog_posted_by = db.Column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('userprofile.sap_ID'), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"BlogPost('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}', '{self.post_picture}', '{self.content}')"
```

class ChatPost(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "chatpost"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
chat_picture = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default_chat.png')
date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
chat_posted_by = db.Column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('userprofile.sap_ID'), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"ChatPost('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}', '{self.chat_picture}', '{self.content}')"
```

class EmailNewsLetter(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "emailnewsletter"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
applied_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"EmailNewsLetter('{self.email}', '{self.applied_date}')"
```

class UserCommitsQuestion(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "usercommitsquestion"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
subject = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
message = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
submit_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)


def __repr__(self):
    return f"UserCommitsQuestion('{self.name}', '{self.email}', '{self.subject}', '{self.message}', '{self.submit_date}')"
```

class PendingTransactions(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "pendingtransactions"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
firstName = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
lastName = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
sap_ID = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
added_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
pmethod = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
ee = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
unt = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
hash = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
pending_owned_by = db.Column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('userprofile.sap_ID'), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"PendingTransactions('''\
                                    '{self.firstName}', '{self.lastName}', '{self.sap_ID}'\
                                    '{self.added_date}', '{self.pmethod}', '{self.ee}'\
                                    '{self.unt}', '{self.hash}'\
                                ''')"
```

class ConfirmedTransactions(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "confirmedtransactions"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
firstName = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
lastName = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
sap_ID = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
added_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
pmethod = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
ee = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
unt = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
hash = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
pending_owned_by = db.Column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('userprofile.sap_ID'), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"PendingTransactions('''\
                                    '{self.firstName}', '{self.lastName}', '{self.sap_ID}'\
                                    '{self.added_date}', '{self.pmethod}', '{self.ee}'\
                                    '{self.unt}', '{self.hash}'\
                                ''')"
```

class WithheldTransactions(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = "withheldtransactions"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
firstName = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
lastName = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
sap_ID = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
added_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
pmethod = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
ee = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
unt = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
hash = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
pending_owned_by = db.Column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('userprofile.sap_ID'), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"PendingTransactions('''\
                                    '{self.firstName}', '{self.lastName}', '{self.sap_ID}'\
                                    '{self.added_date}', '{self.pmethod}', '{self.ee}'\
                                    '{self.unt}', '{self.hash}'\
                                ''')"
```

but when a tried to create a demo data input into the database table UserProfile it return the below error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\instrumentation.py", line 388, 
in _new_state_if_none
state = self._state_constructor(instance, self)
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 893, in 
__get__
obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\instrumentation.py", line 214, 
in _state_constructor
self.dispatch.first_init(self, self.class_)
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", line 322, in 
__call__
fn(*args, **kw)
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 3411, in 
_event_on_first_init
configure_mappers()
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 3299, in 
configure_mappers
mapper._post_configure_properties()
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 1965, in 
_post_configure_properties
prop.init()
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\interfaces.py", line 197, in 
init
self.do_init()
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 2077, 
in do_init
self._process_dependent_arguments()
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 2117, 
in _process_dependent_arguments
expression._only_column_elements(val, attr)
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sapWeb\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 4801, in 
_only_column_elements
raise exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column-based expression object expected for argument 'primaryjoin'; 
got: '<class 'run.BlogPost'>', type <class 'flask_sqlalchemy.model.DefaultMeta'>
```

any other method that will be more easier than this will be accomodated thanks alot.

Comment: Your `account_owner` relationship in `UserProfile` is wrong. You need to define a relationship with each Model. You don't cram them all into one. Have a read up on [Building Relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#orm-tutorial-relationship).

Comment: @PGHE - please can you help me with that have gone through different type of tutor about buiding relationships but still dont understand it, i wont mind and will be very gratefull if you can just help with write the correct code syntax please. thanks

Comment: `account_wallet = db.relationship('UserWallet', backref='user_profile')`

Comment: @PGHE - ok i think i gat you, so i will apply the same to my other model and it will just finally work as i want to. or is there any other error in the code you will like to help me with please. and if you don't mind can you a little explain, which relationship method am trying to use here, and the reason why you say so. thanks and so so sorry for disturbing you this manner please . thanks alot...

Comment: Repeat for all your relationships. Another example could be `blog_post = db.relationship('BlogPost', backref='user_profile')`

Comment: @PGHE - Thanks G. Am so so grateful for your help! It work.